# Alone among the animals on the farm he never laughed

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, word-order

I don't quite understand this sentence, especially the word order. The problem is that what part of the sentence does "alone" modify? Is it "he"? If I understand it right, can this be rewritten to "He alone among the animals on the farm never laughed."?

Comment: Yes, it modifies "he". The word order is used for emotional effect - to convey seriousness and isolation.

Comment: @FeliniusRex It's easy to understand semantically that *alone* modifies *he*. But how comes a adverb modifies a pronoun?

Comment: "He was the only one among the animals who never laughed".

Comment: Alone is not being used as an adverb, but as an adjective. Please look up "alone" in the dictionary.